# Intersection of orbit of prime order element in symplectic algebraic group with maximal subspace subgroup

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups, infinite-groups

Suppose $K$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$.

Let $G = \mathrm{PSp}(2m,K)$ ($m$ odd) and $H = (\mathrm{Sp}(m-1, K) \times \mathrm{Sp}(m+1, K)) \cap G$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ which is the stabiliser of a $(m+1)$-dimensional space in the natural module of $G$.

If $x \in G$ has prime order, is $x^G \cap H$ a finite union of distinct $H$-classes? I think I can show the latter part, but am not sure how to prove finiteness (or whether it's even true!)

Comment: Every element of prime order is conjugate to an element of ${\rm PSp}(2m,F)$ for some fintie subfield of $F$ (in fact you may not need the assumption that the order is prime for that), so there are only finitely many conjugacy classes of such elements. Hence the answer is yes.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help.